# Fish-Activities Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [fish-activities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish-activities) Tag was added today, and it struck me as a bit of an odd choice in tagging. Is there any reason to use [fish-activities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish-activities) instead of, say, [fishing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishing) (retagging the Babel Fish and Pet Fish questions in the process)?

Comment: Ask @OrigamiRobot

Comment: In all honesty, I created the fish-activities tag as a joke.  I do however think it is separate from fishing in the same way a rectangle is separate from a square.  Fish-activities include fishing but fish-activities doesn't have to mean fishing.  I don't think the Babel fish question has anything to do with fishing.  As a whole, I would call this tag slightly less useful than the murder tag.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - Murder is a memetic meta tag. I'm in favor of, well, murdering it, also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think we even *need* a tag for fishing, fishes, or fish activities at all. Fishes and related activity in games is generally consistent of four concepts:

- Resource farming (fishing)
- Minigame or Subquest (fishing)
- A creature in the game (fishes)
- The point of some part of the game, if not the entire game (fishes or fishing)

It's about as meaningful as a tag as, well, a tag for "grappling hooks" would be. It's the kind of concept that you run into a fair enough amount but it doesn't really justify a tag beyond what we already have to classify those things in general (in order: [farming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farming), [mini-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mini-games)/[objectives](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objectives), [characters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) or possibly an [enemies] tag, and the game name).

Comment: Fishing is a video-game [genre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fishing_video_games), but of course is not so popular as other genres. I we need a tag fishing I would use it for that type of games and use farming and other tag, as you suggest, for other purposes.

Comment: @Drake Fishing is about the same as its own genre as farming is its own genre - there are farming games, after all. I don't think it's a significant enough division from other recreational games to require its own separate tag.

Comment: So should we just purge the tag?

Comment: @Raven Go ahead. There's nothing to purge it into, so it's going to have to be a manual job.