# Best of Arqade: 100,000 Questions on Arqade!

Tags: discussion, community-event

Sometime last week, Arqade reached a major milestone.  **The site has reached 100,000 questions!**

Arqade was established a bit over 13 years ago, and currently ranks 25th in question count across the Stack Exchange network.

### The Best of Arqade!

For fun, feel free to share one or more of your favorite post(s), whether it be your own or someone else's, and perhaps a short tidbit on why it's your favorite post.

There won't be any kind of winner like we do for Screenshot of the Week, and we will be skipping Screenshot of the Week this time around (it will resume on August 21st 2023).

Comment: This question sounds bad when taken out of context: [Where can I find homeless people to beat up?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159104/where-can-i-find-homeless-people-to-beat-up)

Comment: Also this one: [I wasted my soul, how can I get a new one?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320225/i-wasted-my-soul-how-can-i-get-a-new-one)

Comment: Congratulations on this milestone!

Comment: @User23415 I think that sounds bad *in context*, as well, but I'm admittedly of a sensitive disposition.

Comment: Does the count include deleted questions?

Comment: @Stevoisiak no, all I did was take the count from the main page of the site, which doesn't include deleted questions.  Looks like we are around 137,000 if you count the deleted questions https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/1788230/total-questions-including-deleted (if that is the correct query - I think it is)

Answer (score 21):

This will forever be the best question on this site just for how it sounds out of context.

[How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)

Comment: I once had this question up on my PC, and my wife (who is not a gamer and not familiar with the ways of Arqade) saw the title of that question. She was ...... greatly confused (and concerned)

Comment: Certainly a classic...

Answer (score 19):

I've always been fond of the question [How do I show my wounds to Robbie?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302391/how-do-i-show-my-wounds-to-robbie). It's mostly because the accepted answer is so ridiculous, but absolutely valid

Comment: Yes I remember that one haha!

Comment: Well that answer is concise, to the point, and right. What can we ask more for an answer.

Answer (score 18):

I love how family is a strong value here on Arqade.

- [My children are useless. What should I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18376/my-children-are-useless-what-should-i-do)
- [What is the fastest way to kill my family?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139127/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-kill-my-family)
- [Will sleeping with my son's wife have a negative effect on our relationship?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174371/will-sleeping-with-my-sons-wife-have-a-negative-effect-on-our-relationship)

Comment: Uhmmmmmm certainly interesting titles to say the least!

Comment: Sounds like just another day in Crusader Kings for sure :)

Answer (score 12):

Probably one of my favorite posts is [What additional features do you get after spending five dollars on Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/318491/what-additional-features-do-you-get-after-spending-five-dollars-on-steam)

[Ave](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/87186/ave) and myself both wrote an answer, and both of the answers were *very* well recieved (over 250 upvotes each!).  Amusingly, we also posted at nearly the same time. However, if you do some digging, my answer was just a few milliseconds or seconds before ave's (<s>I don't remember how much exactly, but it was close</s> it was apparently [44 milliseconds](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12638/is-the-time-stamp-for-posted-answers-actually-accurate-to-the-millisecond#comment40516_12639)).

Lastly, the community took it upon itself to make sure the answers both have the same amount of votes. Even to this day, both answers still have the same amount of votes, and whenever I get the occasional upvote on this answer, I always go back to see if ave's answer is still the same amount of votes, and it always seems to be!

Comment: Before I read this post, I was looking for the answer you linked!

Comment: *Nearly* the same time? They have the same timestamp (2017-09-20 18:31:51Z)! I'm curious how close they are on the backend

Comment: @GammaGames guess it was closer than I thought! But mine is definitely first if you look at the post ID number in the URLs or the [timeline](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/318491/timeline) of the question. I don't know if the Stack Exchange data explorer has a more accurate time or not to look up to see just how close it was.

Comment: Haha I remember this! I dug into SEDE to get the milisecond time a few years ago: [Is the time stamp for posted answers actually accurate to the millisecond?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12638/28182)

Answer (score 12):

I appreciate the diversity and breadth of knowledge that Arqade offers in various fields of learning, such as:

- Chemistry and Breaking Bad: [How do I cook meth?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/130335/4797)
- Social Etiquette and Interpersonal Communication:  [Does shooting people make them dislike me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258362/4797)
- Cultural Studies and Anthropological Analysis: [What benefits does being a Jew give me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/159503/4797)
- Religious Studies and Theology: [Where can I find Jesus Christ?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/158727/4797)
- Biological Experimentation and Medical Research: [How can I increase my chances of getting cancer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/169544/4797)
- Social Psychology and Criminology: [Why can't I stop myself from shooting the President?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/390487/4797)
- Gastronomy and Nutrition: [Are there any disadvantages to eating corpses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244984/4797)
- Medicine / Surgery: [How do I remove people's intestines?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/124287/4797)

Comment: I am very much looking forward to Payday 3

Comment: Lovely form and presentation, galacticninja. +2

Answer (score 11):

A particular favourite of mine is [Which doge represents what number?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160556/which-doge-represents-what-number)

Truly the very best/worst of the site.

Comment: Oh man, comments in that entire thread are amazing. Worth the read.

Answer (score 7):

One of my favorite posts was to [dishonestly get honesty.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/320303/127901) At the time, a large portion of the regular members of [the Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) where playing a bunch of different Incremental and Clicker games. It being a web browser game, combined with with many of those playing it being programmers of some sort led to us finding exploits quite quickly.

Answer (score 6):

Long live [fish-activities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish-activities)

- [Game about being a fish and fish activities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24537/game-about-being-a-fish-and-fish-activities) (10k only)

Background: [Fish-Activities Tag?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2385/fish-activities-tag)

Comment: Guess that was a game identification question that was asked prior to the artifact rule?

Comment: And before the meta tags rule as one of the last straws

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to pick just one great post, but a memorable one is definitely the time when GnomeSlice was *in a bit of a pickle*:

[Do Blasts Pass Through Obsidian?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20846/28182)

For context: this was *before the change to how TNT worked* in Minecraft - attempting to break the TNT would set it off, not simply drop it.

---

For one of my own posts - one that sticks out is the time I manually calculated just how many unique Pokemon could be obtained purely in Pokemon Emerald (i.e. with no trading, cheats/glitches/ACE or Nintendo events etc).

[How many Pokemon can be obtained only in Emerald?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/331103/28182)

On the surface it sounds simple but there's quite a bit of nuance - for example, there's only one Moon Stone available, so you can either evolve Skitty -> Delcatty OR Jigglypuff -> Wigglytuff, but not both. It was an interesting exercise at least!

---

Also I'd like to give a shout-out to Question #1, which (as of writing) is still open, *and* still valid/relevant to modern TF2!

[What is a good strategy to deal with lots of engineers turtling on the other team?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1)

Answer (score 3):

The Classic struggles you have when playing [the-elder-scrolls-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-skyrim), from [dislocating your head](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37805/my-head-keeps-falling-off-what-can-i-do) over [destroying a temple on a wild night out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/uhh-i-got-drunk-and-trashed-a-temple-how-do-i-pick-up-the-mess) to the [wondrous properties of horses defying (most of) gravity and physics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/is-a-horse-actually-faster-than-running). [Romance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37143/grelka-light-of-my-life-fire-of-my-loins-my-sin-my-soul-why-the-hell-wont) can also be problematic at times.

Comment: In my family we always call it "Skyrim horse mode" when something moves improbably easily across terrain.

Comment: I recall horses in Farming Simulator being able to climb vertical mountain cliffs as if they were insects. It's a game focusing on realism, supposedly...